# Dynamic Actions for InfoBoxes with Bing Maps

Tags: maps, bing-maps

I am creating a site that implements the Bing map control.
I have placed the pushpins, and they will show infoboxes when the user clicks on a pin.

What I need to do now is add actions to the infobox.  I can do this statically with the action: option.  I want to do it dynamically, as each site can have a different set of actions I want to present to the user.

I have built the string that has the actions in it, unfortunately the infobox wants an object, not a string, and I don't know which object it wants, nor how to turn the string into the proper object.

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you don't have a "setActions" you can use the "setOptions" on Infobox.

```
infobox.setOptions(infoboxOptions);
```

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675208.aspx

The options itself could be created like this, with just the actions:

```
var infoboxOptions = {
    actions:[
        {label: 'test1', eventHandler: testEvent1}, 
        {label: 'test2', eventHandler: testEvent2}]};
```

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675210.aspx

You can call this anytime you want, thus adding for instance more actions to the infobox.

Now, you mention you have a string? I'm guessing you're talking about the JSON representation of the "infoboxOptions" or such. You can use something like

```
jQuery.parseJSON(jsonString); //if using jQuery
```

You can also do it programmatically, thus probably with some conditional logic:

```
var myActions = [];

if(A) {
    myActions.push( {label: 'test1', eventHandler: testEvent1});
}
if(B) {
    myActions.push( {label: 'test2', eventHandler: testEvent2});
}
if(C) {
    myActions.push( {label: 'test3', eventHandler: testEvent3});
}
infobox.setOptions({ actions: myActions});
```

Comment: I implemented the conditional logic approach, and that worked out great.

That you so much for the help.